# Issue Installing tensorflow-gpu

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

```
A:\Py-Charm\pythonProject> pip install tensorflow-gpu
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Using cached tensorflow-gpu-2.12.0.tar.gz (2.6 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [43 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "A:\Py-Charm\pythonProject\.venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 35, in __init__
          parsed = _parse_requirement(requirement_string)
        File "A:\Py-Charm\pythonProject\.venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 64, in parse_requirement
          return _parse_requirement(Tokenizer(source, rules=DEFAULT_RULES))
        File "A:\Py-Charm\pythonProject\.venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 82, in _parse_requirement
          url, specifier, marker = _parse_requirement_details(tokenizer)
        File "A:\Py-Charm\pythonProject\.venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 126, in _parse_requirement_details
          marker = _parse_requirement_marker(
        File "A:\Py-Charm\pythonProject\.venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 147, in _parse_requirement_marker
          tokenizer.raise_syntax_error(
        File "A:\Py-Charm\pythonProject\.venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\_tokenizer.py", line 165, in raise_syntax_error
          raise ParserSyntaxError(
      setuptools.extern.packaging._tokenizer.ParserSyntaxError: Expected end or semicolon (after name and no valid version specifier)
          python_version>"3.7"
                        ^

      The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-07c73rw5\tensorflow-gpu_1193296dd3aa48408f6cc23cdc8e1ce9\setup.py", line 40, in <module>
          setuptools.setup()
        File "A:\Py-Charm\pythonProject\.venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 102, in setup
          _install_setup_requires(attrs)
        File "A:\Py-Charm\pythonProject\.venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 73, in _install_setup_requires
          dist.parse_config_files(ignore_option_errors=True)
        File "A:\Py-Charm\pythonProject\.venv\lib\site-packages\_virtualenv.py", line 23, in parse_config_files
          result = old_parse_config_files(self, *args, **kwargs)
        File "A:\Py-Charm\pythonProject\.venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 667, in parse_config_files
          self._finalize_requires()
        File "A:\Py-Charm\pythonProject\.venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 396, in _finalize_requires
          self._normalize_requires()
        File "A:\Py-Charm\pythonProject\.venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 410, in _normalize_requires
          meta._normalized_install_requires = {
        File "A:\Py-Charm\pythonProject\.venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 410, in <dictcomp>
          meta._normalized_install_requires = {
        File "A:\Py-Charm\pythonProject\.venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 37, in __init__
          raise InvalidRequirement(str(e)) from e
      setuptools.extern.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Expected end or semicolon (after name and no valid version specifier)
          python_version>"3.7"
                        ^
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Environment Information:

```
Python Version: 3.9.13
CUDA Installed: Yes
cuDNN Installed: Yes
GPU: RTX 4070
IDE: PyCharm
```

I have followed the installation steps carefully, ensuring that CUDA and cuDNN are properly set up on my system. However, I am facing difficulties during the installation process, and the error message seems related to a package requirement syntax issue.

I have already tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

- Ensured that CUDA and cuDNN installations are correct.
- Checked compatibility between TensorFlow version and GPU architecture.
- Verified that Python version is compatible with TensorFlow.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: have you tried pytorch?

Answer (score 0):

Kindy install the required Hardware and Software requirements by this using this link [Software and Hardware](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#hardware_requirements) . and follow the step by step instructions.

Once you have installed all the required software and hardware requirements please follow below steps.

> 1. System requirements:
>    Ubuntu 16.04 or higher (64-bit)

TensorFlow only officially support Ubuntu. However, the following instructions may also work for other Linux distros.

> 2. GPU setup :

Install the NVIDIA GPU driver if you have not. You can use the following command to verify it is installed.

```
nvidia-smi
```

> 3. Install TensorFlow :

TensorFlow requires a recent version of pip, so upgrade your pip installation to be sure you're running the latest version.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then, install TensorFlow with pip.

```
# For GPU users
  pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]
# For CPU users
  pip install tensorflow
```

> 4. Verify the installation:

Verify the GPU setup:

```
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```

If a list of GPU devices is returned, you've installed TensorFlow successfully.

Follow the above steps to install the tensorflow-gpu.